# google assistant with react native

Tags: react-native, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I developed one react native application. now I want to integrate Google Assistant in the app, I will provide one mic button, if the user click on it, the google assistant need to be enabled, and I need response from the google.

I am working in smart home project, I want to integrate google assistant api in React native app, I seen the library support only python. Please suggest me the best way I can embed google assistant in my app.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the dialogflow integration with react native? that could help you do what you want. If you are building a smart home integration I would assume you are already in dialogflow to some extent.

https://github.com/innFactory/react-native-dialogflow